# how do you add a third column as the sum of the first two columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried the SELECT col1, col2, col1+col2 AS col3 FROM table_name command but it only shows the third column but it can not be saved to the table. When I close the SSMS and reopen it nothing is added to the table.

Comment: Why would you expect anything to be added to the table? It's just a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: A `SELECT` statement is a read-only operation that returns data. It does not modify data or the table schema. It seems you may want a view or computed column to avoid repeating the expression.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're asking for a *computed column*

```
Alter table <table>
add col3 as col1 + col2
```